# How to email a link to a facebook app installed on a business page

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

When I email a link to my app installed on my Facebook business page, the email recipient does not get redirected to the facebook app unless they are logged into facebook.  If the person clicks the emailed link and they are not logged into facebook they get linked to the facebook home page to either log-in or set up an account.

This is the link to my facebook app that I have emailed that most people do not get directed to the app, whereas I do want them to be able to see the facebook app if it's possible even if they are not logged into facebook at the time.

https://www.facebook.com/LuxuryVacationsIncome/app_483454071672592

I have been to technical support of the company that created the app and they could not resolve the issue